# COINTIFs in VBA returns True or False

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate my first report, and everything worked fine until the moment of trying to write an Excel function into cell:

```
With Worksheets("Report")
        .Select
        .Range("F4").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(data!R2C2:R" & lastrow & "C2;Report!RC[-5];data!R2C5:R" & lastrow & "C5;""Deleted"";data!R2C11:R" & lastrow & "C11;" > "&0)"
```

At first I've been comparing last condition to 1 and it worked fine, but after trying to implement >0 it started to return True somehow.

Are there any other solutions how to properly implement ">0" condition or should I use multiple "=" with all the possible values?

Comment: Why don't you add the complete **relevant** code i.e. a `With` has to have a corresponding `End With`, `lastrow` is `0`,... Also, although your list separator is `;`, the list separator in VBA is still `,`.

Comment: Also, you need to double up all quotes that are part of the formula so: `"=COUNTIFS(data!R2C2:R" & lastrow & "C2,Report!RC[-5],data!R2C5:R" & lastrow & "C5,""Deleted"",data!R2C11:R" & lastrow & "C11,"">0"")"`

Answer (score 2):

Write the formula into an intermediate variable first and dump it to the immediate window.

```
dim f as string
f = "=COUNTIFS(data!R2C2:R" & lastrow & "C2;Report!RC[-5];data!R2C5:R" & lastrow & "C5;""Deleted"";data!R2C11:R" & lastrow & "C11;" > "&0)"
Debug.Print f
```

--> You will get "True". So why is that? Somewhere you got lost when writing the formula. VBA sees the whole term as logical term, not as string. Break the long line into pieces:

```
f = "=COUNTIFS(data!R2C2:R" & lastRow _
    & "C2;Report!RC[-5];data!R2C5:R" & lastRow _
    & "C5;""Deleted"";data!R2C11:R" & lastRow _
    & "C11;" > "&0)"
```

Now it gets more obvious: You got lost at the last piece that reads `"C11;" > "&0)"`. VBA compares the long left part of your formula with the short right part and returns `True`. This True is written into the cell.

What you probably meant (see the difference?)

```
f = "=COUNTIFS(data!R2C2:R" & lastRow _
    & "C2;Report!RC[-5];data!R2C5:R" & lastRow _
    & "C5;""Deleted"";data!R2C11:R" & lastRow _
    & "C11 > 0)"
.Range("F4").FormulaR1C1 = f
```